# Magento 2 autoload error : "Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\HTML" doesn't exist

Tags: magento2.3, profiler, autoloader

Am getting the following error after I enabled the profiler from the command line

> Autoload error Cannot create standard driver output, class
> "Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\HTML" doesn't
> exist.

I tried disabling the profiler But the error still persists.

My Magento version : 2.3.5, Varnish Enabled.
Does anyone have the idea why this happens? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if you type: `bin/magento dev:profiler:enable HTML`, with caps.

The correct syntax is: `bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html` (lowercase),

or simply: `bin/magento dev:profiler:enable`, since `html` is the default.

If the error message persists after disabling the profiler, make sure to clean all caches, and run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` if necessary.